# Using the Cordova Network Plugin Connection… How detect if a connection is really slow?

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I’m using this plugin to display a webview if you’re connected to internet… But if we are connected to a wifi who dispatches a really slow connection? H
ow we can advice to the users about this?

I have a good service to handle this and these work fine when my app changes from internet to no internet condition, but fails when there is "Wifi but no internet condition".

I mean, i know this method:

```
downlinkMax
Downlink Max Speed

Returns: string
```

But… How can i know when a connection is slow?? What kind of data returns this method? What’s a speed connection “tolerable”?

I don’t want to have a service like:

```
  checkConnection(): boolean{
    if(this.network.type == 'none' || this.network.type == 'unknown'){
      return false;
    }
    else{
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Because i don’t know the speed of that connection…

Thanks

PD: Plugin Related

[Network Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/)

Comment: I prefer to use an actual http url to send a ping. Not an easy and simple way but if you already have a server, worth trying.

Comment: Finally i do that, download a small resource from my web and add a listener